# Regex for selecting images

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I wrote regular expresion that allow to select images and separate it by parts. Here is it [example](https://regex101.com/r/dR8jU6/1). Generally it works without any problem, but i found that regular expression work incorrect if multiple images go after each other. How can i fix this problem?

Regex

```
<img(.*?)src=(?:'|")((?:.*?)\.(?:gif))(?:'|")(.*?)\/?>
```

Comment: What's wrong? that's exactly the same as when you have multiple images after each other https://regex101.com/r/dR8jU6/2

Comment: I need to fetch 3 parts from each gif images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input_html_here);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute("src");
    // do stuff here
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Regexes are 100% the WRONG tool to use for this job.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method. May you please tell me what's `$input_html_here` which you have passed it as a argument to `loadHTML()` function?

Comment: Thanks, i will try to use this, but as i can remember i can not use DOMDocument cause my html can`t be parsed with it, my html code is not fully valid/

Comment: @Shafizadeh Well presumably there is some HTML which is currently being passed to `preg_match`. Just pass it to `loadHTML` here.

Comment: @Kison Use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` to hide any parsing errors. It's HTML, so it will give *something*, and in this case ignoring errors is reasonable since you're only interested in the `img` tags, which don't have contents.